# How widespread was the use of Aguado's "Tripodium", and are similar devices still used today?

Tags: guitar, technique, classical-guitar, posture

[Dionisio Aguado](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dionisio_Aguado_y_Garc%C3%ADa) (1784-1849) developed his "Tripodium" (also referred to online as a "Tripodion" or simply tripod) to aid support, positioning and clear sound projection while playing classical guitar (see picture below).

**How widespread was the use of this device?**

**Are similar devices still used much now?** [This](http://gildeavalle.wordpress.com/2013/12/03/dionisio-aguados-tripodium-now-at-my-workshop/) link shows a modern maker of this device, but I'm pretty sure I've seen guitarists using other kinds of guitar-supports, for instance when playing more than one guitar live.

[image]

Comment: I haven't heard of the tripodium, but in terms of similar support devices, I've heard of at least one guitarist (Paul Galbraith) who uses a cello endpin to support the guitar in an upright, cello-like position. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6FYMVgOW2XM

Comment: @CalebHines: It's more than a cello like reposition, check out the sounding box it rests on, increasing the surface area of the resonance ! Brilliant find.

Comment: I remember seeing more than one pop performer use the following guitar holder as to allow a quick change from a strapped on electric to an acoustic: http://www.musicstandsalone.com/gracieconventionalacousticguitarstand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tripodium are not commonly used by classical guitarists at this time. Most performers stick with a simple foot stool. What you have to remember is that in Aguado's (and indeed Carcassi's) time it was equally likely that you would be playing with bare fingers, than your finger nails. In fact, even in the 20th century using your nails was somewhat controversial:
http://books.google.com/books?id=ocwwb7WImqoC&pg=PA51&lpg=PA51&dq=classical+guitar+nails+controversy&source=bl&ots=MOtjleoAQ_&sig=6IPUeEJtj52YRtYRmVz-z8UI-BA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Q6-oU7GEMqrlsASD3IHYAw&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=classical%20guitar%20nails%20controversy&f=false

As nearly all classical guitarists today use their fingernails, the extra projection from the special stand  is often not needed. I needn't mention the modern convenience of microphones. Also, notice how much smaller the guitars of those times were. Certainly not the booming concert hall instruments we have today, but something more closely associated with intimate performances.

However, I'm sure some modern revivalists would love to use a Tripodium. If you are interested, you should build one yourself - it will be sure to turn heads, especially at a baroque music society.

Oh, and last of all, yes, guitarists do use a special stand to play multiple guitars:

http://www.musicstandsalone.com/gracieguitarstands

To my knowledge they have always been called gracie stands. They don't have anything to do with projection, or at least in the intended rock concert setting there is little point in that facet of their construction. Rather, they just make it easier to stand up and play or two guitars.

Answer (score 3):

I've build one for myself using 3D printing:

[image: Tripodium]

The necessary files can be downloaded here: [Printables](https://www.printables.com/model/579449-tripodium-for-classical-guitar)